# How calculate an arithmetic expression using recursion, having problem with brackets

Tags: c, recursion, math, clion, brackets

Im trying to write a code that will take mathematical input from the user [example: (1+2x3), (2x(3+4)),
(2x(3+4)-(6/2))...] and print the result, using recursion.

I was able to come up with a code that works for expressions like the in the example however, it seems that expression containing too many brackets right beside each other [example :(2x((3+4)-(6/2))), ((2x3+4)-(6/2))] are giving me wrong answers.

I am **not allowed** to use array for this so instead I check every character individually. Also the actual **order of operation is not relevant**, all calculation need to be made from **left to right**, and the only thing that matters is **brackets**. For example  (1+2x3) = 9, and not 7. (1+(2x3)) = 7 however. The basic expression must start with "(" and end with ")". Also I can assume all the numbers will be from 0-9.

This is the main function. Currently I'm assuming that the expression is built in a valid way, and I start the recursion by making sure the first char is "(" and then put 0 as a default of sort, so the nptnum is already the next char when starting.

The "1" in the middle is used for bracket counting, however **I didn't find a use for this in the code so far.**

```
int main() {
    printf("enter an expression:\n") ;
    char nptnum ;
    int num = 0 ;

    scanf(" %c", &nptnum) ;
    if(nptnum == '('){
        scanf(" %c", &nptnum) ;
        num = elevator(0, 1, nptnum) ;
    }
    printf("this is num %d\n", num) ;

return 0 ;
}
```

This is the recursive code. Again, so far the bracketcounter **is not used** in a meaningful way.

The idea is to:

1. When reaching ( call the function.
2. Calculate everything inside until reaching ).
3. return that sum.
4. Repeat

```
int elevator(int number, int brackets, char nptnum) {
    int bracketcount = brackets ;
    int num ;
    char operand ;

    num = number ;
   
    if(nptnum >= '0' && nptnum <= '9') {
        num = (nptnum - 48) ;
        scanf(" %c", &nptnum) ;
    }

    //if the first character is ) that means there is no calculation to be made
    if(nptnum == ')'){
        bracketcount--;
        return num ;
    }

    //get the operand  
    if(nptnum == '+' || nptnum == '-' || nptnum == '*' || nptnum == '/') {
        operand = nptnum ;
        scanf(" %c", &nptnum) ;
    }

    int num2 ;
    //recursion in case of new brackets
    if(nptnum == '(') {
        while(nptnum == '('){
            bracketcount++ ;
            scanf(" %c", &nptnum) ;
        }
        num2 = elevator(0, bracketcount, nptnum) ;
        scanf(" %c", &nptnum) ;

    } else if (nptnum >= '0' && nptnum <= '9') {
        num2 = (nptnum - 48) ;
        scanf(" %c", &nptnum) ;
        printf("third char: %c\n", nptnum) ;

    }
    int sum ;
    printf("num is: %d, num2 is: %d, op is : %c\n", num, num2, operand) ;

    //operator is a simple arithmetic calculation function 
    sum = operator(num, num2, operand) ;

    printf("op result %d\n", sum) ;
    printf("before check %c and bracket %d\n", nptnum, bracketcount) ;
    //a recursive call for the rest of the expression when there are no new brackets
    if(nptnum != ')'){
        bracketcount-- ;
        sum = elevator(sum, bracketcount, nptnum) ;
        printf("this is sum: %d\n", sum) ;
    }
    return sum ;
}
```

operator function

```
int operator (int num1, int num2 , char op) {
    switch (op) {
        case '+' : {
            return (num1 + num2) ;
            break ;
        }
        case '-' : {
            return num1 - num2 ;
            break ;
        }
        case '*' : {
            return num1 * num2 ;
            break ;
        }
        case '/' : {
            return num1 / num2 ;
            break ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I am not allowed to use array for this" --> note that each _string literal_ like `" %c"`, `"op result %d\n"` is an _array_.  But I suppose some arrays are OK.

Comment: `while(nptnum == '('){  bracketcount++ ;   scanf(" %c", &nptnum) ;  }` is not matched with a like `if(nptnum == ')'){  bracketcount--;  return num ;  }`.  I would expect no return until `bracketcount` became 0 (or 1).  Even better, drop `bracketcount` and the `while(nptnum == '(')` loop.  Simply recurse for each `'('`.

Comment: In my experience you do not need an explicit bracket counter.  As chux points out, let recursion handle each subexpression in parentheses.

Comment: I recommend simple [*recursive descent parsing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser).  Have a function `getexpr` which parses `+` and `-` expressions.  Have it call `geterm` to get a term, then read an operator and make sure it's `+` or `-`, then call `geterm` again.  In `geterm`, call `getpri` to get a "primary expression", then read an operator and make sure it's `*` or `/`, then call `getpri` again.  Finally, in `getpri`, you should either find some digits, of if you find a `(`, make a recursive call to `getexpr`.

Comment: @SteveSummit Excuse my ignorance but there are a few things I dont understand. First, are you suggesting additions to what I wrote or a completely new way? Second does "parsing" mean "isolate" and does "term" mean "number" ? Third, what is the start of the recursion, ```getexpr```? Forth, why did you divide between the parsing of +,- and *,/?, Fifth, are those function supposed to get paramters and return things? It almost look like a loop of sort. Im currently trying to understand how what you suggested would work

Comment: @SteveSummit Im having a hard time understanding the process of the functions suggested. ```getpri``` seem to be the beginning? it seem to either find (and return?) a digit, or strat a new recursive line. So lets say the first recursion start, it calls ```getexpr``` wichh in turn call```getterm```  to get... a ```*``` or ```\``` expression if the opreators match? and if they dont it doesnt call ```getpri``` so I am left with a number and...not sure . I dont understand what kind of info ```getterm``` and ```getexpr``` are getting/returning

Comment: @SteveSummit If you can point me towards a simple example of a similar process, so I can see how it work exactly it would be extremely helpful

Comment: @SteveSummit, evaluation in this exercise is strictly left-to-right, so there is no need (in fact, it would be wrong) to model the expression in a way that produces precedence of multiplicative operations over additive ones.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Ah, yes, I missed that.

Comment: @דולבמנג'ם I was suggesting a completely different way.  And given that you're not trying to implement precedence relations among operators, my suggestion was pretty much irrelevant.  But if you're curious about recursive descent, there's a pretty complete example on [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser)... oh, and I see John has added an answer with a nice explanation, also.

Comment: @דולב מנג'ם – 
In your examples you use 'x' for multiplication, in your program `'*'`; you have to make up your mind.

Comment: See also [How to get and evaluate the Expressions from a string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472680) and its answers, especially [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472680#66104290).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for everyone that helped and explained what I didn't understand! I was able to write code that does what I need to, pretty sure it does basically what people here said I should do (perhaps a bit messy).

I will explain once more what this code does. It takes an expression in the form of (1+2*3(6/2)) for example and print the final result of the calculation.

It does the calculation from left to right and ignore normal order of operations rules, but still give priority to expressions in brackets.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int evaluator() ;
int operator (int num1, int num2 , char op) ;

int main() {
    printf("enter an expression:\n") ;
    char npt = scanf(" %c", &npt) ;
    int num = 0 ;
    num = evaluator() ;
    printf("this is num %d\n", num) ;

return 0 ;
}

int elevator() {
    char npt, op ;
    int number = 0, number2 = 0, number3 = 0, count = 0;
    if(npt != ')') {
        scanf("%c", &npt) ;
    }

    while (npt != ')') {
        if(npt == '(') {
            number = evaluator() ;
            scanf(" %c", &npt) ;
        } else if(npt >= '0' && npt <= '9') {
            number = npt-'0';         
            scanf(" %c", &npt) ;
        }

        if(npt == '+' || npt == '-' || npt == '*' || npt == '/') {
            op = npt ;           
            scanf(" %c", &npt) ;
        }

        if(npt== '(') {
            number3 = evaluator() ;            
            scanf(" %c", &npt) ;
        }
        else if (npt >= '0' && npt <= '9') {
            number3 = npt - '0';
            scanf(" %c", &npt) ;            
        }
            number = operator(number, number3, op) ;           
    }
    return number ;
}

int operator (int num1, int num2 , char op) {
    switch (op) {
        case '+' : {
            return (num1 + num2) ;
            break ;
        }
        case '-' : {
            return num1 - num2 ;
            break ;
        }
        case '*' : {
            return num1 * num2 ;
            break ;
        }
        case '/' : {
            return num1 / num2 ;
            break ;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon the comments and add a few of my own:

- You should not need to count parentheses explicitly if you're not validating the input expression.  Instead, recurse when you read an opening parenthesis and return from that recursive call when you consume a closing parenthesis.  That will naturally create an appropriate pairing of your opening and closing parentheses.
- If you do want to validate then you probably still don't need to *count* nesting levels, but you may want to pass a parameter that tells your parser whether to expect a closing parenthesis.  The top-level call (see also next) would not expect a closing parenthesis, whereas all others would.
- You do not need to (and probably should not) prime the computation in `main()` by checking whether the input starts with a parenthesis and providing special handling for that case.  There's no reason why your expression evaluator function should not be able to handle that itself.
- This would very naturally be written as a recursive descent parser.  Steve recommends *refactoring* your existing `elevator()` function (strange name -- did you mean *evaluator*?) into several functions with more narrowly-defined responsibilities.  That would be based on modeling expressions along these lines (Steve recommended a different, more conventional model that includes precedence of multiplicative operations over additive ones):

  - An *expression* takes one of these forms:

    - a *primary*, or
    - a sequence of *expression*, *operator*, *primary*
  - A *primary* takes one of these forms:

    - a (non-negative, integer) *number*, or
    - a sequence of '**(**', *expression*, '**)**'
  - An *operator* is one of these: **+**, **-**, *****, **/** (or did you want **x** for multiplication?  The question is inconsistent about that, but there are reasons to prefer **x**.)

  Your existing code addresses most of that, but it would be clearer, easier to debug, and handle your parenthesis-nesting problem if you refactored it into several functions that map more directly onto that model:

  - The top-level function is `get_expression()` (or a similar name of your preference).  It does this:

    1. Parse a *primary* for an initial left-hand operand, by calling the function for that.
    2. Attempt to read an *operator* (you can have a function for that, if you like).
    3. One of these:

       - if an operator was read, then parse another *primary* for a right-hand operand, and use that, together with the left-hand operand and operator, to compute a new left-hand operand. Then go back to (2);
       - otherwise, the left-hand operand is the result.  If a closing parenthesis was read instead of an operator then either that should be pushed back, or this function should have a way to signal that to its caller.
  - That depends on a function `get_primary()` (or similar) to parse a *primary*.  Depending on the next character, it does one of these:

    - if the next character is a '**(**', then this function calls `get_expression()` to parse an expression, then consumes a closing '**)**';
    - otherwise, parse and return a *number*.

Comment: Your comment has been very helpful. However I still have a few question. 1.  What does "parsing" means exactly? I dont know that word (not native english speaker).  2.When you say  "If a closing parenthesis was read instead of an operator then either that should be pushed back" what do you mean? getting rid of it? 3. What doe consuming a closing ')' mean? 4. And by "compute and report a result" do you mean returning the value?

Comment: @דולבמנג'ם "Parsing" means reading some text very carefully, figuring out exactly what each bit of it means.  It's what a compiler (or any programming language translator) does when reading source code and figuring out what it "means".

Comment: To your other questions: any time you're reading input — whether it's from an i/o stream like C's `stdin`, or reading characters one by one out of a string — it's useful to think about whether you've "consumed" a character.  That is, you often look at the next character, and decide what to do with it.  If you know what to do with it, you remove it from the input, but if you don't know what to do with it, and if you want to leave it on the input for somebody else to deal with, you can usually do that, too.

Comment: There are three different operations you might want to perform: (1) you might have an operation that *removes* a character from the input and returns it to you; (2) you might have an operation that *peeks* at the next character in the input, but without removing it; and (3) you might have an operation that takes a character removed from the input by operation #1, and *pushes it back* onto the input, so that someone else will read it later.  In C, reading from a `FILE *` stream, operation #1 is `getc`, and operation #3 is `ungetc`, and to peek you have to do `getc` and then `ungetc`.

Comment: But if you're reading characters from a string you're moving along, all three operations are straightforward.  If you have a pointer `char *p` pointing at your string, then operation #1 is typically `c = *p++`, and operation #2 is typically `c = *p`, and operation #3 is typically `*--p = c`.